# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{x^4+y^4}=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Study the continuity of the following function at the point $ (0,0) $.
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{x^4+y^4} & \text{ if } (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\ 
 0& \text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0) 
\end{cases}$$

If I take trajectories, it can be conjectured that the limit of said function is $ 0 $. But when limiting the function $ e ^ {- 1 / (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2)} $ I don't know how to do it, any help to limit that function in such a way that the limit is $ 0 $.

Comment: I can't solve the problem either, but maybe a different title would attract more people, e.g. "Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{x^4+y^4}=0$".

Comment: I already put it, thank you very much for the idea of ​​the title.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$ x^4 + y^4 = \frac12(x^2-y^2)^2 + \frac12(x^2+y^2)^2 \ge \frac12(x^2+y^2)^2$$
so
$$ \frac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{x^4 + y^4} \le 2 \frac{e^{-1/(x^2+y^2)}}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} $$
Since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+y^2) = 0$, $x^2+y^2>0$ it is enough to show that
$$ \lim_{u\to 0_+} \frac{e^{-1/u}}{u^2} = 0$$
or
$$ \lim_{z\to +\infty} z^2 e^{-z} = 0$$
Do you know how to show this?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.